# Which module to use for storing small cache files in Perl?

Tags: perl, cpan

I've written a script that needs to store a small string in-between runs. Which CPAN module could I use to make the process as simple as possible? Ideally I'd want something like:

```
use That::Module;
my $static_data = read_config( 'script-name' ); # read from e.g. ~/.script-name.data
$static_data++;
write_config( 'script-name', $static_data ); # write to e.g. ~/.script-name.data
```

I don't need any parsing of the file, just storage. There's a lot of different OSes and places to store these files in out there, which is why I don't want to do that part myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) for portable persistence of Perl data structures and [File::HomeDir](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aHomeDir) for portable "general config place" finding:

```
use File::HomeDir;
use FindBin qw($Script);
use Storable qw(nstore);

# Generate absolute path like:
# /home/stas/.local/share/script.pl.data
my $file = File::Spec->catfile(File::HomeDir->my_data(), "$Script.data");

# Network order for better endianess compatibility
nstore \%table, $file;
$hashref = retrieve($file);
```

Comment: There's a lot of different OSes and places to store these files in out there, which is why I don't want to do that part myself.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed that you also need a portable way for determining the storage place. Edited my answer to suit better your need!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a single string (eg, 'abcd1234'), just use a normal file and write to it with `open`.

If you're looking for something a bit more advanced, take a look at [Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple/Simple.pm) or [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS/XS.pm). Conifg::Simple has its own function to write out to a file, and JSON can just use a plain `open`.

Comment: There's a lot of different OSes and places to store these files in out there, which is why I don't want to do that part myself.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you - http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col53.html. But I think you cannot avoid using work with files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know how to do this (rather than rolling by hand) is to use [DBM::Deep](http://p3rl.org/DBM%3a%3aDeep).

Every time I post about this module I get hate posts responding that its too slow, so please don't do that.